# Building solution copies tremendous amount of system assemblies to output directory

Tags: build, visual-studio-2017

When building my solution in VS 2017 (15.9.3) there are **97** *System.xxx.dll*'s being copied into the output directory along with the none-Framework dlls. Among the system dlls are BCLs like e.g. *System.Collections.dll*, *System.Data.Common.dll*, *System.Globalization.dll* and *System.IO.dll*.
The solution consists of 4 small C# Projects (2 dlls and 2 WinForms) with some NuGet references to *log4net*, *System.Data.SQLite*, *Oracle.ManagedDataAccess*, *Npgsql* and *Npgsql*'s dependencies. All projects are targeting .NET Framework 4.6.2 and I am not aware of having different project settings than in other projects, where nothing similar happens.
Any ideas how to restore "normal" behaviour? Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 0):

These are probably System.* assemblies that are shipped as NuGet dependencies for your packages, not necessarily part of the .NET Framework that's installed globally.

For example, looking at the dependencies for Npgsql, I see these dependencies:

- System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe (>= 4.5.0)
- System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions (>= 4.5.0)
- System.ValueTuple (>= 4.5.0)

The first two are not part of the .NET Framework as installed by Windows.

Similarly, `System.Data.SQLite` is not a Microsoft package, nor part of the .NET Framework install.  It is owned by the SQLite team, and they've just happened to use the System.* root namespace.

Comment: The dlls you mentioned are the ones I called _non-Framework dlls_. I know that these have to copied locally. The ones that bother me are e.g. `System.Collections.dll`, `System.Data.Common`, `System.Runtime` and similar ones.

Comment: Exactly. I found things like System.Console, System.Linq, System.Reflection in the list as well. Those r definitely belongs to Framework